# How to use ajax callback on auto complete field inside a block settings form?

Tags: 8, forms, blocks, ajax

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);
    $selected = 'value of a field';
    $form['node'] = [
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#title' => $this->t('My content type'),
      '#target_type' => 'node',
      '#selection_settings' => [
        'target_bundles' => ['bundle'],
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'my_ajax_callback'],
        'wrapper' => 'my-specializations',
      ],
    ];

    $form['first_select'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => [0 => 'x', 1 => 'y'],
      '#title' => 'doctor',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'my_ajax_callback'],
        'wrapper' => 'my-specializations',
      ],
    ];

    $form['specializations'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Specializations'),
      '#options' => $this->specialization($selected),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="my-specializations">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    return $form;
  }

 private function specialization($selected) {
    if (!empty($selected)) {
      return ['1' => 'a', '2' => 'b'];
    }
    else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  public function my_ajax_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['specializations'];
  }
```

The ajax call back function is not working on auto complete field. How can I make it working on the auto complete field?

And on the `first-select` it is working but I am getting an error:

`TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\AjaxRenderer::renderResponse() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormAjaxResponseBuilder.php on line 89 in Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\AjaxRenderer->renderResponse() (line 53 of /var/www/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/AjaxRenderer.php)`

Can you someone tells me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code that declares the `doctor_ajax_callback` function? I don't see `public function doctor_ajax_callback(...`

Comment: That function is actually `my_ajax_callback`

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title's question

```
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::my_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'my-specializations',
    'event' => 'change', // run ajax on change
    'keypress' => TRUE, // if set to TRUE, then the element's #ajax['event'] will be triggered if the ENTER key is pressed while the element has focus.
  ],
```

Comment: I am getting this error now. `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable`

Comment: @Ahmad turns out when using BlockBase, it requires a different approach. See [Ajax Calls on BlockBase extensions don't work](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2817499). You'll have to do a solution [like in #46](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2798261#comment-12735075)